# C# ошибка Expected: not equal to 0 But was: 0

Tags: c#, тестирование, хеширование

Решаю данную задачу https://ulearn.me/Course/basicprogramming2/Praktika_Readonly_bytes__1a5e39b3-9b7f-46c5-bb3c-ab024f2c8714

По заданию создал класс ReadonlyBytes

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace hashes
{
    public class ReadonlyBytes : IEnumerable<byte>
    {
        private readonly byte[] byteArray;
        private readonly int hashCode;
        public int Length { get; }

        public ReadonlyBytes(params byte[] array)
        {
            if (array == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            Length = array.Length;
            byteArray = array;
            hashCode = GetHashCode();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder("[");
            result.Append(String.Join(", ", byteArray));
            result.Append("]");
            return result.ToString();
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            UInt64 result = 0;
            UInt64 p = 16777619;
            var shift = Length / 50;
            for (var i = 0; i < Length; i += 1 + shift)
            {
                result ^= (uint)byteArray[i];
                result = (result * p) % int.MaxValue;
            }
            return (int)(result);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            var castedObj = obj as ReadonlyBytes;
            if (this.hashCode != castedObj.hashCode || this.Length != castedObj.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.Length; i++)
                    if (this[i] != castedObj[i])
                        return false;
                return true;
            }
        }

        public byte this[int index] => byteArray[index];

        public IEnumerator<byte> GetEnumerator()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Length; i++)
                yield return byteArray[i];
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Все тесты данный код проходит, но при попытке послать данное решение выводит лог

> Как минимум один из тестов не пройден! Название теста:
>   HashCodeDiffers_IfArraysDiffersOnTheLastElementOnly Сообщение:
>   Expected: not equal to 0   But was:  0
>
> Стек вызовов:    at
>   checking.ReadonlyBytes_HiddenTests.HashCodeDiffers_IfArraysDiffersOnTheLastElementOnly()
>   Когда может возникать эта ошибка? И как это можно исправить?

Comment: Возвращается одинаковый хэшкод для разных массивов (отличающихся только последним элементом). Судя по коду такое у вас будет часто, если элементов больше 50

Comment: @АндрейNOP брал данный алгоритм https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FNV
для функции GetHashCode() и когда тестил она возвращала только уникальные хэши.

Comment: Меня смущает это: `i += 1 + shift`, если элементов будет больше 50, то вы будете перепрыгивать через элементы, ну и соответственно выдавать одинаковый хэш

Comment: var castedObj = obj as ReadonlyBytes; obj может быть null и у вас будет ошибка при castedObj.hashCode, т.к. оператор as возвращает null если не удается привести к нужному типу.

Comment: Вы попробуйте сравнить другой класс не равный null со своим

Comment: @AlexsandrTer спасибо, отследил ошибку с оператором as, правда ошибка с 50 элементами, которую описал NOP осталась.

Comment: @АндрейNOP пытался переписать строку с var shift таким образом:
  var shift = Length / 50;
            if (Length > 0)
                shift = Length / (Length * 2);
И все равно не получается уложиться во время. Что-то делаю не так?

Comment: есть такая вещь, как векторизация, можно попробовать для ускорения вычислений

Answer (score 1):

Убрать `sift` совсем, а вычисления производить в конструкторе. В `GetHashCode()` возвращать результат.